# A question regarding the solution of a quadratic polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions, complex-dynamics

I'd like to know why the following statement (taken from *Iteration of Rational Functions* by *Beardon*) is true: "Now $z^2+c$ has two fixed points, say $\alpha$ and $\beta$, in $\mathbb{C}$, and as these are solutions of $$z^2-z+c=0,$$ they satisfy $$\alpha+\beta=1,\quad\alpha\beta=c."$$ I know this seems trivial but the answer is escaping me.

Answer (score 3):

These are [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots, then by the Factor Theorem, $(z-\alpha)$ and $(z-\beta)$ are factors, so $z^2-z+c=(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)$. Equating coefficients yields $\alpha+\beta=1$ and $\alpha\beta=c$.